# React d3 transition requestAnimationFrame is not supported error

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, jestjs, enzyme

I use d3 with transition in my react component , when I test the component, I get this `requestAnimationFrame is not supported in Node` exception thrown.
I read [why](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9102#issuecomment-283873039) the error occours, is there any way of overcoming this thrown exception other than by removing the thrown exception code mentioned in above [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9102#issuecomment-283873039)?